# How to influence the URL to access a registered Delphi WebService

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-xe2

We've written a webservice dll with Delphi XE2 and it is running in our IIS7 server, accessible with the url http://server/webservice.dll/soap

To be able to debug the service, I've created a webservice.exe project, which can be run in the WebAppDebugger of Delphi. The problem now arrises that the webservice running in the debugger is accessible with the url http://localhost/webservice.webservice/soap

Our client application has the last part of the url "webservice.dll/soap" hardcoded (security reasons) so i cannot change that when testing with our client application, the server-address part "http://server/" is configurable in the client.

So, my question: How can i register the debug service in my webappdebugger to use an url like my production dll?

Comment: A simpler approach maybe to use URLRewrite in IIS to change the webservice.dll/soap to the URL dictated by the webappdebugger. See http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite You can turn rules on and off in IIS management

Comment: @MarjanVenema Ths would have been possible if the WebAppDebugger is running locally in IIS. But it is a separate process, run from within the Delphi IDE, and runs a webserver locally

Answer (score 6):

I've found the solution myself ;-)

In the initialization of the debugform there was the following line:

TWebAppSockObjectFactory.Create('Webservice');

changing this to:

TWebAppSockObjectFactory.Create('dll');

made the overall address change to http://localhost/Webservice.dll/

This did leave a small problem that the debugger project had to be renamed to Webservice.exe in stead of WebserverDebug.exe as it was called, but moving it to subfolder made this rename possible.

Comment: Even though i did find a "workaround" to my own problem, it still interests me to find out how you can influence the resulting URL when running a webservice in the WebAppDebugger...